# Convert flac to wav with tags and cover art

Tags: command-line, audio, wav

I have a bunch of flac files with tags and cover art. I need to convert them to wav and retain the tags and cover art. I also need to do this in a terminal on a headless Raspberry Pi 4B running Raspbian Buster.

I have read in many posts that cover art cannot be added to wav files, but Foobar2000 does it very well on the Windows side.

So how would you go about achieving the goals stated above?

Edit: Before posting my question, I tried many different things, including the following:

- flac in decoding mode, with the --keep-foreign-metadata option, is very quick, but it does not carry the tags and cover art into the resulting wav
- ffmpeg with "-c:v copy -f wav -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3" is a bit slower than flac, but it does transfer the tags, but not the cover art
- 'ffmpeg -i some.wav -i some.jpg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (Front)" target.wav' gives an error about wav being a one-stream format and does not store the cover art.

I could probably run Foobar under Wine on the RPi, but this poor RPi is already running a few heavy services 24/7, so I am very careful not to overload it, hence the goal to do this from the command line. I have also accessed the drive (where the flac files are stored) from my laptop and done the work with Foobar under Windows 10, but my network is not so fast, so this is quite slow.

Considering that ffmpeg can handle the tags, I guess the remaining issue is the cover art.

Thanks.